# Code execution stops after for loop?

Tags: c#, api, nuget

So i'm trying to make a program that uses the League of Legends API in C#.

I found a NuGet package that makes using the API a lot easier.

> Everything works fine so far except the code execution stops after the
>   first for loop i use.

Here's the code: (of course i took out the api key)

```
string[] summnames;
long[] champids;
long[] teamids;
long[] champs;

CreepScoreAPI.ParticipantLive[] enemy;
CreepScoreAPI.ParticipantLive[] ally;
CreepScoreAPI.ParticipantLive centsumm;
CreepScoreAPI.ParticipantLive[] champsss;
CreepScoreAPI.ChampionStatic[] champions;
CreepScoreAPI.Summoner[] sumners;
CreepScoreAPI.League[] leaguesz;

Dictionary<string, List<CreepScoreAPI.League>>[] leagues;

int[] champidsint;
string[] champnames;

int s;
int se;

public async Task<string> game(string summname)
{
    string data;

    CreepScoreAPI.CreepScore cs = new CreepScoreAPI.CreepScore("api key");

    var summoner = await cs.RetrieveSummoner(CreepScoreAPI.CreepScore.Region.EUNE, summname);
    long summid = summoner.id;
    var thegame = await summoner.RetrieveCurrentGameInfo();

    CreepScoreAPI.ParticipantLive[] participants = thegame.participants.ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { summnames[i] = participants[i].summonerName;}

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { champids[i] = participants[i].championId;}

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { teamids[i] = participants[i].teamIdLong;}

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { champids[i] = participants[i].championId;}

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { champidsint[i] = Convert.ToInt32(champids[i]);}

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { champions[i] = await cs.RetrieveChampionData( CreepScoreAPI.CreepScore.Region.EUNE, champidsint[i], CreepScoreAPI.Constants.StaticDataConstants.ChampData.All, "en_US", "7.1.1",false ); }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { champnames[i] = champions[i].name; }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { sumners[i] = await cs.RetrieveSummoner(CreepScoreAPI.CreepScore.Region.EUNE, summnames[i]); }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) { leagues[i] = await sumners[i].RetrieveLeague(); }

    /* teamsorter */
    foreach (CreepScoreAPI.ParticipantLive p in participants)
    {
        if (p.summonerId == summid)
        {
            centsumm = p;
        }

        if (p.teamIdLong == centsumm.teamIdLong)
        {
            ally[s] = p;
            s++;
        }
        if (p.teamIdLong != centsumm.teamIdLong)
        {
            enemy[se] = p;
            se++;
        }
    }

    data = " I'LL FORMAT A STRING THAT OUTPUTS ALL THE DATA I NEED HERE";
    return data;
}
```

When I call the game function and input the name of the summoner i gets to the first for loop and doesn't even populate the summnames[] array and stops execution with no error code.

What I'm trying to do with all the loops is populate the variables I made before the function so I can use them later for other purposes.

Comment: You never assign an array to `summnames`, or any of the other arrays.  And if you do and make them all of size 10 then you can just use one `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should assign all the arrays and set their length to at least 10.

This could solve the problem.

Comment: What do you think "assign all the arrays" signifies to somebody so green that he doesn't know enough to initialize them? You can't assume that it'll signify anything very specific.

Comment: ...on second thought, if OP accepted the answer, it clearly signified enough in his case.